# What's the recommended way to add content with images and text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, content-management-system, ruby-on-rails-3.2

What's the recommended way to add content to my rails app ? pages with cloud hosted images like amazon s3& formatted text ?
What I want is just to create a tutorial pages that are easily linked with an index page.

Is there a recommended approach rather than re-inventing the wheel ? what's the popular gems out there ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need fixed content you have just to create an html in the public folder with the html that you need, and link directly from your index view to them.

In order to store the images in the cloud, just upload them and put a reference link to your page fixed content to it.

Otherwise, if you are building a dynamic page that you may upload new images and etc...

Use the [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem. It is a good way to not reinvent the wheel!